# Visual Studio Code fails to start on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed Visual Studio Code 32 bit version (1.71.1) on a Windows 7 machine. I checked the box that said to launch it after I click Finish. The "wait" mouse cursor showed for a second or two, then nothing.

I tried double clicking the desktop icon with the same results. No error message. Not indication that it attempted to start. I did change the desktop icon to "Run as administrator" and that got me the prompt to allow changes to the system, but again, nothing comes up.

Any idea of what is going on? Is there a specific .NET version I need to have?

Comment: I hate to ask this question but... Have you tried restarting your computer after installing? Also are you sure your computer is 32 bit and not 64? Otherwise your best bet may be to reinstall the program. Without us knowing anything else about your specific situation there's very little we can do that you couldn't get from the troubleshooting pages that are a Google search away.

Comment: Did a search originally before coming here and did not find anything. Not saying I used search terms correctly, but I did try. Secondly, like an idiot I assumed it was 32 bit. It was 64 bit. Uninstalled and installed 64 bit version. Still does not start. Finally ran it and got an error. Prior to this, no error. Here are the details:  Sorry. Paste did not work. It was in NTDll.dll.

Answer (score 1):

The installed 32 bit (1.71.1) version is not compatible with Windows 7.

The [last version compatible with win7](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70) is the version 1.70 from July 2022.

A windows 7 compatible version can be downloaded from

https://update.code.visualstudio.com/1.70.2/win32/stable

or

https://az764295.vo.msecnd.net/stable/e4503b30fc78200f846c62cf8091b76ff5547662/VSCodeSetup-ia32-1.70.2.exe

Comment: I tried to install VS code to Win7 based on VM. Your campatible link is working well. Thank you.